# Module not found when running geopandas identity

Tags: geopandas

I'm attempting to conduct a vector identity using two shapefiles in geopandas. When this is run I get the following error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas.sindex'`

I've done a quick search and there is no module called geopandas.sindex related to vector identity or anything like it. My geopandas is installed under anaconda and it is installed as I am able to import geopandas.

Here is an excerpt from my code.

```
import geopandas as gpd
geo_df1 = gpd.read_file("shapefile1.shp")
geo_df2 = gpd.read_file("shapefile2.shp")
geo_df3 = gpd.overlay(geo_df1,geo_df2,how="identity")`
```

I strongly suspect something has gone wrong in my installation as this operation was done correctly historically so any recommendations towards fixing the installation is appreciated. The expected result will be being able to run the geopandas operation successfully.

Comment: I would recommend reinstalling `geopandas`. This should not happen as .sindex is part of the package. Did you install it using pip or conda from conda-forge?

Comment: I've been trying both today mixing and matching uninstalling and installing it, I've just attempted to reinstall it via anaconda and something looks to be working so I will report back on status.